# How to pull multiple records using SQL statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Thanks in advance for your help.

I'm working with an application that a user developed. It prompts you for something to search for and then performs a basic query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Entry=[ENTRY];
```

I cannot change that format. All I can do is modify the text of [ENTRY]. Is there a way I can pull multiple records without modifying the structure of the statement itself? For Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Entry='COW | APPL* | ROO*';
```

to acheive the results:

```
COW, APPLE, APPLES, ROOF, ROOM, ROOSTER;
```

Please excuse the rudimentary example - Thanks,

Blake

Comment: `WHERE IN ('COW', 'APPL*', 'ROO*')`

Comment: +1 for being a well structured and valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This totally depends on the code. If there is possibility than you can use Sql injection method to request multiple records.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Entry='COW' OR Entry ='APPL' OR Entry = 'ROO';
```

Following this example your variable [ENTRY] should be this:

```
[ENTRY] = "'COW' OR Entry ='APPL' OR Entry = 'ROO'";
```

Note, that this will not work, if your [ENTRY] variable is protected against sql injection.

EDIT:
So here is an sql injection method not knowing the table name:
this should be your string to copy in:

```
COW' OR 1 = '1
```

Comment: Thanks - When I ran the code I put in the answer, I received an error basically saying "You completed an invalid command." This tells me it is probably not protected against sql injection. Problem is... I don't know what the user called the "Entry" column.

Comment: Try to find the piece of code where he initialize the database ( you have access to source code no? )

Comment: Unfortunately I do not :/

Comment: Than you should ask user for it, because no way to find out, the other method is to perform an sql injection. I will attach a link alsoÉ: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: If you find this useful, than please consider accepting it as an answer. In the link provided in my previous comment, you can find many examples of sql injection. Try them and hope for a little bit of luck. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Because you and Adhi both replied with the same answer at the same time, I can't accept either answer. Instead I +1'd your last comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the developer didn't prevent sql injection, you can try add `;` and create a new query.

If you can change `=` to `IN`.

Comment: Thanks - When I ran the code I put in the answer, I received an error basically saying "You completed an invalid command." This tells me it is probably not protected against sql injection. Problem is... I don't know what the user called the "Entry" column.

Comment: try `entry = '0;SELECT * FROM Table'`
query will lock like this:
`SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Entry=0;SELECT * FROM Table;`

Comment: I have no idea what "entry" or "Table" are though so I can't even use injection. Thanks though!

Comment: you can try using SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to get the tables

Answer (score 2):

Provided SQL injection is allowed, you can input an SQL query in the user input field as follows:

`COW' OR Entry = 'APPL%' OR Entry = 'ROO%`

This should make the SQL statement look like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE Entry='COW' OR Entry = 'APPL%' OR Entry = 'ROO%';
```

Comment: Exactly what I wound up doing!! Problem is... I don't know what the user called the "Entry" column. But thanks!

Comment: The only way I know how to solve that would be to look at the database schema to figure out the field name OR if you have the source code then look at where the SQL query is generated for the field name referenced.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have either :/ Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.. now my problem is that I don't know what the user called the column in question lol.

If I knew what "Entry" was I would do:

```
[Entry] = COW' OR WHERE Entry='APPL*' OR WHERE Entry='ROO*
```

so that the final SQL statement reads:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Entry='COW' OR WHERE Entry='APPL*' OR WHERE Entry='ROO*';
```

giving me what I was looking for.